# How could I get all versions of Openflow Switch Specification?

Tags: openflow, sdn

Recently I am studying SDN and Openflow. I want to read all versions of Openflow Switch Specification. When I went to [Openflow](http://archive.openflow.org/), I only found Openflow Spec 0.8.9/0.9.0/1.0.0/1.1.0 and it told me to visit [ONF](https://www.opennetworking.org/) for more information. But ONF made me confused because I couldn't find any obvious clue. I also searched in Google,  but I am not sure if the result is intact. Could anybody give me some hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to the link on ONF https://www.opennetworking.org/technical-communities/areas/specification to read the specifications.

Please note that OpenFlow versions 1.0 and 1.3 have been mostly used in commercial products, so a good understanding of these two protocol versions should really be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your note !